# How to use another step inside a main step in Ruby Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, capybara

I have the step_definition called "ForPreEdit.rb", whose tag is @preed when I want to run this separate step (which works perfectly).
I also have the step_definition called "LoginSolic.rb", whose tag is @loginSolicitante (also works perfectly).
Inside "When .... End" of step_definition "ForPreEdit" I need to run step_definition "LoginSolic" to login. I'm using the following syntax for this:
"steps %Q {
When I want to Login as Requester
}"

When executing, no error is reported, simply the code is being ignored. My version of Gemfile Cucumber is 5.2. More code details below:

```
09 When('I perform my Login as Requester:') do |table|
10 # LOGIN
11 steps %Q{
12 When I want to Login as Requester
13 }
14 find('#Country').find(:xpath, 'option[5]').select_option
15 sleep 5
16 find('#DocumentType').find(:xpath, 'option[2]').select_option
```

Lines 11, 12 and 13 are ignored, the program starts executing from line 14, and on line 14 an error occurs because it depends on the execution of line 12. Again, when running separately, both work perfectly.

Comment: Since your'e just tring to run a single step could you try `step 'I want to Login as Requester'` and see if it behaves any differently

Answer (score 1):

In general nesting steps is an anti-patten and should be avoided. As you are using ruby you should do the following ideally with all your steps.

1. Make each step implementation a call to a helper method
2. When you want to nest steps replace the nesting with a call to a helper method and do the nesting in the helper method

An example

```
module LoginStepHelper
  def create_registered_user
    User.create ...
    ...
  end

  def login(as: )
    fill_in 'name', with: @i.name
    fill_in 'password', with: @i.password
    submit_form
  end

  def register_and_login
    login as: create_registered_user
  end
end
World LoginStepHelper

Given "I am registered" do
  @i = create_registered_user
end

When "I login" do
  login as: @i
end


# BAD
Given "I am logged in" do
   steps %Q{
     Given "I am registered"
     And "I login" 
   }
end

# Good
Given "I am logged in" do
  register_and_login
end
```

It is always much cleaner and simpler to extract any nesting into a helper method, and its particularly easy if you ensure all your step definitions are implemented by default as calls to helper methods. As your suite of cukes grows the benefits you get from avoiding nesting in steps multiply.

There are a set of features and steps illustrating this concept in more depth here https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up/tree/master/features. I think you will gain alot by studying them.